# Probability of success on first trial - finite events - known probability of success

Tags: probability

Good day folks,

Say I know 3 out of 8 balls are winning balls. I want to know the probability that the first ball picked from the urn is one of these 3.
I assume I can use the multiplication rule where p is success and f failure and therefore: p x f x f x f x f x f x f x f = p x f^7 = 0.375 x 0.9625^7 = 0.375 x 0.76525322 = 0.2869

Perhaps I am overthinking it but grateful for confirmation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Each of the three winning balls has a $\frac 18$ of being first, so the answer is $\frac 38$.

Comment: Thank you, I was overthinking it....